# Why isnt the value from 'clave' being inserted into my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want the user to enter an email, password and user type. In the database, what should be saved is the email, password, user type, time and date. All of those are being saved correctly in the database, except the password. I've changed the name, checked many times and it still won't save the password, but it will save everything else. The password is simple text and nothing is encrypted. This is the form ('clave' is password):

```
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="OFF">
            <label for="">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="myemail@gmail.com" required>
            <br><br>
            <label for="">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="clave" placeholder="*********" required>
            <br><br>
            <label for="">User type</label>
            <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
                <option selected>Pick a type of user</option>
                <option value="1">Admin</option>
                <option value="2">Employee</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" name="crear">Crear cuenta</button>
        </form>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['crear']) && !empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['clave']) && ($_POST['tipo'])) 
    {
        //recibimos los datos del formulario
        $correo = $_POST['correo']; 
        $clave = $_POST['clave']; 
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo']; 

        //incluir el archivo conexion
        include("sesion5_conexion.php");

        //configuramos la fecha y la hora
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Mazatlan"); 
        $hora = date("H:i:s"); 
        $fecha = date("Y-m-d"); 


        //query para insertar la consulta
        $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (username, clave, tipo, hora, fecha) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"); 

        // Use "ssi" for string, string, integer parameters
        $sentencia->bind_param("ssiss", $correo, $clave, $tipo, $hora, $fecha);
        
        //ejecutamos la consulta
        if ($sentencia->execute()) {
            echo '<script> alert("Se ha creado el usuario") </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script> alert("NO se creo el usuario. Error: ' . $sentencia->error . '") </script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($clave)` gives the password? I would store datetime as a datetime object in db, not individual fields. You cant extract whatever you need from that. The password should be hashed. Maybe browser has security feature that requires password fields have their type as `password`... I dont think that is true currently though. Checking payload and value server receives should give you info though

Comment: @user3783243 Hi thank you for the response! This is just an assignment and my teacher asked us to not encrypt anything yet. I also tried changing the input type from text to password and that didn't help. I even changed the column name too. I just ran the snippet you gave and it prints the password I enter correctly, I put the snippet above the include(). But if I put it above the INSERT INTO, it's empty.

Comment: I ended up moving 'correo', 'clave', and 'tipo' under the date and time configs and it worked!

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would make a difference, unless `sesion5_conexion.php` resets the variables.

Comment: @Barmar me neither, but it worked. The logic is essentially the same.

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($clave);` before and after the `include` line.

Comment: @Barmar I kept forgetting to respond so if you still care, it was the conexion file causing problems! I had $clave in that file as a variable to connect to the database